# Rank based on one column and use another column if tie breaker is needed

Tags: excel, vba, criteria, rank, tie

I have some "names" of groups in column A and I want to rank each "name" based on its value in column B.  If any of the "names" have the same value in column B, it will need to look to column C to determine a tie breaker (then column D value if any of those are tied).  I'm looking for either VBA or a formula (which I could insert into my VBA code).  The real life data I'm working with is more complicated than this and sort will not work for what I'm looking to accomplish.  I don't want to use SUMPRODUCT (or the like) at the start because I only need it to consider the data in other columns if there is a tie.

[image]

I used to be fairly decent with VBA, but it's been a long time since I've used it, so I'm very rusty.  I have no idea where to start, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain why Sort will not work for you?  It's pretty powerful, extensive, and quite capable of handling a wide range of datatypes.  Is it important that the rows stay in the order they currently are in?

Comment: There's more data columns and information involved then just these 4 columns.  This is the basic function of what i'm attempting to do and if i can figure out how to rank based only on column B and any tie columns in column B (those names only) look to column C for tie breaker, then i know i can figure out how to add some of the other layers not provided in this example.

Comment: I understand that you have more data, but I still don't understand why sort won't work for you.  You can sort in a hierarchical manner, exactly like you want.  For example, sort your data according to column B's data from highest to lowest value, and then sort your data according to column C's data from highest to lowest value, etc.  Each sort will work with the previous sorts, not overwrite them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in VBA would require a fair bit of coding. In cases where you want to rank avoiding ties, the common solution is to create a helper column where you combine the two target columns. For example you could add the Issue column to the NDX column divided by 1000 (or more depending on how many decimal places you're using), so the first row would read 6.74420%.

You would then just RANK on the helper column.

In your example, the helper column formula would be:

```
=$B$2:$B$13+$D$2:$D$13/1000
```

And your ranking formula would be:

```
=RANK.EQ(F2,$F$2#)
```

... and so on down the rows.

Comment: This is a good thought.  I think some of the data bits i havent provided might cause issues, but i think there may be another method of working around those that i didnt think of previously.  Thank you!